# concept of binary indicator function

Tags: mathematical-statistics, indicator-function

In my textbook it talks about the binary indicator function. It says "The distribution represents the fact that X is always equal to the value 1, in other words, it is a constant". Is big X the state space? What is the meaning of the big X in this context?

[image]

Comment: Both X's--$X$ and $\mathcal X$--are clearly described in this passage.  What, then, do you mean by "big X" and what are you trying to ask?

Comment: I strongly deprecate your textbook's use of $\mathcal X$ for the state space, $X$ for the random variable, and $x$ for the value taken on by $X$.  Worse yet is $p(x) = 1/5$ without any restrictions on the value of $x$ and the choice of example to illustrate the concept of an indicator function. As Dorothy Parker once wrote in a review for _The New Yorker,_ your textbook is "not a book to be put down lightly; it should be thrown with great force!"

Comment: @DilipSarwate Recommendations for alternative nomenclature?

Comment: @Alexis That whole passage is so bad not just in nomenclature and notation but also in fundamental concepts that it is not worth anyone's while to devise alternative nomenclature.

Comment: @DilipSarwate Well you singled out nomenclature, which was why I asked for a recommended alternative (just for general purposes, not for an edit to this question specifically). But I get your position better now. :)

Answer (score 1):

$X$ is a random variable that can take on values $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$.

An indicator variable takes on a value of $1$ if the expression inside of the indicator function is true and $0$ otherwise.

For the degenerate distribution, the indicator variable will take on a value of $1$ when $x=1$ and $0$ otherwise. We can see that for $x=1, p(X=1)=I(x=1)=1$ while for $x\ne 1, p(X=x)=I(x=1)=0$. In other words, the probability that the random variable takes on a value of $1$ is $1$ so $X$ always takes on a value  of $1$.